# Inefficient Regularized Logistic Regression with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, classification, regression

I am a machine learning noob attemping to implement regularized logistic regression via Newton's method.

The data have two features which are supposed to be expanded to 28 through finding all monomial terms of (u,v) up to degree 6

My code converges to the correct solution of norm(theta)=0.9384 after around 500 or so iterations when it should only take around 15 for lambda = 10, though the exercise is based on Matlab instead of Python. Each cycle of the parameter update is also very slow with my code and I am not sure exactly why. If anyone could explain why my code takes so many iterations to converge and why each iteration is painfully slow I would be very grateful!

The data are taken from Andrew Ng's open course exercise 5. The problem information and data can be found here http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex5/ex5.html
although I posted the data and my code below.

X data with two features

```
0.051267,0.69956
-0.092742,0.68494
-0.21371,0.69225
-0.375,0.50219
-0.51325,0.46564
-0.52477,0.2098
-0.39804,0.034357
-0.30588,-0.19225
0.016705,-0.40424
0.13191,-0.51389
0.38537,-0.56506
0.52938,-0.5212
0.63882,-0.24342
0.73675,-0.18494
0.54666,0.48757
0.322,0.5826
0.16647,0.53874
-0.046659,0.81652
-0.17339,0.69956
-0.47869,0.63377
-0.60541,0.59722
-0.62846,0.33406
-0.59389,0.005117
-0.42108,-0.27266
-0.11578,-0.39693
0.20104,-0.60161
0.46601,-0.53582
0.67339,-0.53582
-0.13882,0.54605
-0.29435,0.77997
-0.26555,0.96272
-0.16187,0.8019
-0.17339,0.64839
-0.28283,0.47295
-0.36348,0.31213
-0.30012,0.027047
-0.23675,-0.21418
-0.06394,-0.18494
0.062788,-0.16301
0.22984,-0.41155
0.2932,-0.2288
0.48329,-0.18494
0.64459,-0.14108
0.46025,0.012427
0.6273,0.15863
0.57546,0.26827
0.72523,0.44371
0.22408,0.52412
0.44297,0.67032
0.322,0.69225
0.13767,0.57529
-0.0063364,0.39985
-0.092742,0.55336
-0.20795,0.35599
-0.20795,0.17325
-0.43836,0.21711
-0.21947,-0.016813
-0.13882,-0.27266
0.18376,0.93348
0.22408,0.77997
0.29896,0.61915
0.50634,0.75804
0.61578,0.7288
0.60426,0.59722
0.76555,0.50219
0.92684,0.3633
0.82316,0.27558
0.96141,0.085526
0.93836,0.012427
0.86348,-0.082602
0.89804,-0.20687
0.85196,-0.36769
0.82892,-0.5212
0.79435,-0.55775
0.59274,-0.7405
0.51786,-0.5943
0.46601,-0.41886
0.35081,-0.57968
0.28744,-0.76974
0.085829,-0.75512
0.14919,-0.57968
-0.13306,-0.4481
-0.40956,-0.41155
-0.39228,-0.25804
-0.74366,-0.25804
-0.69758,0.041667
-0.75518,0.2902
-0.69758,0.68494
-0.4038,0.70687
-0.38076,0.91886
-0.50749,0.90424
-0.54781,0.70687
0.10311,0.77997
0.057028,0.91886
-0.10426,0.99196
-0.081221,1.1089
0.28744,1.087
0.39689,0.82383
0.63882,0.88962
0.82316,0.66301
0.67339,0.64108
1.0709,0.10015
-0.046659,-0.57968
-0.23675,-0.63816
-0.15035,-0.36769
-0.49021,-0.3019
-0.46717,-0.13377
-0.28859,-0.060673
-0.61118,-0.067982
-0.66302,-0.21418
-0.59965,-0.41886
-0.72638,-0.082602
-0.83007,0.31213
-0.72062,0.53874
-0.59389,0.49488
-0.48445,0.99927
-0.0063364,0.99927
```

Y data

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

My code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

def sigmoid(theta, x):

    return 1/(1 + math.exp(-1*theta.T.dot(x)))


def cost_function(X, y, theta):

    s = 0
    for i in range(m):
        loss = -y[i]*np.log(sigmoid(theta, X[i])) - (1-y[i])*np.log(1-sigmoid(theta, X[i]))
        s += loss
    s /= m
    s += (lamb/(2*m))*sum(theta[j]**2 for j in range(1, 28)) 
    return s


def gradient(theta, X, y):
    # add regularization terms
    add_column = theta * (lamb/m)
    add_column[0] = 0
    a = sum((sigmoid(theta, X[i]) - y[i])*X[i] + add_column for i in range(m))/m
    return a


def hessian(theta, X, reg_matrix):

    matrix = []
    for i in range(28):
        row = []
        for j in range(28):
            cell = sum(sigmoid(theta, X[k])*(1-sigmoid(theta, X[k]))*X[k][i]*X[k][j] for k in range(m))
            row.append(cell)
        matrix.append(row)

    H = np.array(matrix)
    H = np.add(H, reg_matrix)
    return H


def newtons_method(theta, iterations):

    for i in range(iterations):
        g = gradient(theta, X, y)
        H = hessian(theta, X, reg_matrix)
        theta = theta - np.linalg.inv(H).dot(g)
        cost = cost_function(X,y,theta)
        print(cost)    
    return theta

def map_feature(u, v): # expand features according to problem instructions

    new_row = [] 
    new_row.append(1)
    new_row.append(u)
    new_row.append(v)
    new_row.append(u**2)
    new_row.append(u*v)
    new_row.append(v**2)
    new_row.append(u**3)
    new_row.append(u**2*v)
    new_row.append(u*v**2)
    new_row.append(v**3)
    new_row.append(u**4)
    new_row.append(u**3*v)
    new_row.append(u*v**3)
    new_row.append(v**4)
    new_row.append(u**2*v**2)
    new_row.append(u**5)
    new_row.append(u**4*v)
    new_row.append(u*v**4)
    new_row.append(v**5)
    new_row.append(u**2*v**3)
    new_row.append(u**3*v**2)
    new_row.append(u**6)
    new_row.append(u**5*v)
    new_row.append(u*v**5)
    new_row.append(v**6)
    new_row.append(u**4*v**2)
    new_row.append(u**2*v**4)
    new_row.append(u**3*v**3)
    return np.array(new_row)

with open('ex5Logx.dat', 'r') as f:
    array = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        array.append(line.strip().split(','))

    for a in array:

        a[0], a[1] = float(a[0]), float(a[1].strip())

    xdata= np.array(array)

with open('ex5Logy.dat', 'r') as f:
    array = []
    for line in f.readlines():
        array.append(line.strip())

    for i in range(len(array)):
        array[i] = float(array[i])
    ydata= np.array(array)


X_df = pd.DataFrame(xdata, columns=['score1', 'score2'])

y_df = pd.DataFrame(ydata, columns=['acceptence'])

m = len(y_df)

iterations = 15

ones = np.ones((m,1)) # intercept term in first column
X = np.array(X_df)
X = np.append(ones, X, axis=1)
y = np.array(y_df).flatten()

new_X = [] # prepare new array for expanded features
for i in range(m):
    new_row = map_feature(X[i][1], X[i][2])

    new_X.append(new_row)

X = np.array(new_X)

theta = np.array([0 for i in range(28)]) # initialize parameters to 0

lamb = 10 # lambda constant for regularization

reg_matrix = np.zeros((28,28),dtype=int) # n+1*n+1 regularization matrix 
np.fill_diagonal(reg_matrix, 1)
reg_matrix[0] = 0
reg_matrix = (lamb/m)*reg_matrix

theta = newtons_method(theta, iterations)
print(np.linalg.norm(theta))
```

Comment: This seems like a better question for Code Review.  The goal of that site is to improve already-working code; here the focus is more on fixing things that are broken.

Comment: Regarding Speed: 1) Don't use lists and list comprehensions. Allocate a numpy array (eg. np.zeros, np.empty) and then fill it with data. 2) Have a look at Numba or Cython to speed up the looping. 

Have also a look on existing code: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html or other answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794754/logistic-regression-using-scipy

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but i went through one tutorial on Logistic Regression using Newton's method(http://thelaziestprogrammer.com/sharrington/math-of-machine-learning/solving-logreg-newtons-method) and it's implementation of Newton's method is little different from yours.Actually there is one major difference. In Newton's method it's adding product of inv of hessian and gradient to theta whereas you are subtracting. I know about logistic regression normal way not using newton's method. Apart from that it seems that you are using loops in Cost function and Hessian which i think can be done with one statement in numpy than looping.

I would suggest refer to attached link which i gave as it has done all implementation in python numpy and there are no loops. Loops which you have created are impacting performance.

Comment: Yeah the minus sign was odd to me as well but that is how the equation was written on the problem set, and the correct answer is reached. Changing it to addition actually causes my parameters to grow exponentially and results in a divide by zero error in the sigmoid function.